# Duda con HashSet y LinkedHastSet con iteradores

Tags: java

mi duda es una pregunta teórica, espero que no estén excluidas de la web este tipo de preguntas.

Estoy recién adentrándome al mundo de las colecciones en java y según tengo entendido, la interfaz set se encarga de colecciones de datos que no estén repetidas y en las cuales el orden no sea relevante, o eso tengo entendido hasta ahora.

Mi duda viene al hacer el siguiente código:

```java
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class Prueba {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Set<String> var =  new HashSet<String>();
            HashSet<String>varHS = new HashSet<String>();
            LinkedHashSet<String> varLHS = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

            varHS.add("1");
            varHS.add("2");
            varHS.add("3");
            varHS.add("4");
            varHS.add("5");
            varHS.add("6");

            varLHS.add("1");
            varLHS.add("2");
            varLHS.add("3");
            varLHS.add("4");
            varLHS.add("5");
            varLHS.add("6");

            Iterator<String> ivarHS = varHS.iterator();
            Iterator<String> ivarLHS = varLHS.iterator();

            while(ivarHS.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(ivarHS.next());
            }

            while(ivarLHS.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(ivarLHS.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

Se supone en el la colección de tipo HashSet los valores se devuelven en un orden completamente aleatorio y que en la variable de tipo LinkedHashSet los valores se devuelven en el orden de insercción, ¿Estoy equivocado?

Entonces, ¿por qué cuando muestro ambas variables con un objeto iterador, salen exactamente en el orden que las ingresé?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Manuel si puedes realizar este tipo de preguntas pero en este caso tenías también un error tipógrafico, teníes incorrecta la declaración : Iterator<String> ivarLHS = varHS.iterator();, debe ser Iterator<String> ivarLHS = varLHS.iterator(); para que notes la diferencia debes agregar más datos, saludos.

Comment: La única forma de entender esto, es viendo como funciona internamente, de lo contrario, no resolverás dudas.

Answer (score 1):

Como indica la documentación **un [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) es una versión ordenada de [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)** la cual mantiene una lista doblemente vinculada en todos los elementos.

> [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) se usa cuando importe el orden de iteración. Cuando
>   itera a través de un [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), el orden es impredecible, mientras
>   que [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) le permite recorrer los elementos en el orden
>   en que se insertaron.

Revisa este ejemplo de acuerdo al código de tu pregunta:

```
    Set<String> var =  new HashSet<String>();
    HashSet<String> varHS = new HashSet<String>();
    LinkedHashSet<String> varLHS = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    varHS.add("1");
    varHS.add("2");
    varHS.add("3");            
    varHS.add("4");
    varHS.add("5");            
    varHS.add("6");
    varHS.add("10");
    varHS.add("11");
    varHS.add("12");

    varLHS.add("1");
    varLHS.add("2");
    varLHS.add("3");            
    varLHS.add("4");
    varLHS.add("5");            
    varLHS.add("6");
    varLHS.add("10");
    varLHS.add("11");
    varLHS.add("12");

    Iterator<String> ivarHS = varHS.iterator();
    Iterator<String> ivarLHS = varLHS.iterator();

    while(ivarHS.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("HashSet : " + ivarHS.next());
    }

    while(ivarLHS.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("LinkedHashSet : " + ivarLHS.next());
    }
```

En la salida podrás notar que únicamente el [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) mantiene el ordenamiento:

```
HashSet : 11
HashSet : 1
HashSet : 12
HashSet : 2
HashSet : 3
HashSet : 4
HashSet : 5
HashSet : 6
HashSet : 10

LinkedHashSet : 1
LinkedHashSet : 2
LinkedHashSet : 3
LinkedHashSet : 4
LinkedHashSet : 5
LinkedHashSet : 6
LinkedHashSet : 10
LinkedHashSet : 11
LinkedHashSet : 12
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con datos mas complejos, y tienes un error en el código:

```
Iterator<String> ivarHS = varHS.iterator();
Iterator<String> ivarLHS = varHS.iterator();
```

tienes mal escrito **varHS**, deberia ser **varLHS**:

```
Iterator<String> ivarHS = varHS.iterator();
Iterator<String> ivarLHS = varLHS.iterator();
```